# Create a copy of a database in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Edition and I have a database `dbCRM` with many tables and other database objects.

Now I created a database `dbCRMTest` and I want to copy all the database objects from the first database `dbCRM` to second `dbCRMTest`.

How do we achieve this?

Comment: And at no point in your searching, did you come across DTS packages?

Comment: Here you go:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704572/create-duplicate-sql-database-for-testing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy SQL Server 2008 R2 database from one machine to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866321/how-to-copy-sql-server-2008-r2-database-from-one-machine-to-another)

Answer (score 2):

1)  Backup dbCRM

2)  Restore dbCRM backup to dbCRMTest with overwrite